# Filtering In mongoose aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a listing object with filters. I need to create an aggregation to filter the listings based on filters.
This is a listing object example

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5c484ec4cb1e150b1efce101",
    "details": {
      "title": "Villa 1",
      "description": "Description about Villa 1"
    },
    "options": {
      "features": [
        "5c482b1ff9f18807694040c6",
        "5c482b2ef9f18807694040c7",
        "5c482b3af9f18807694040c8",
        "5c482b49f9f18807694040c9"
      ],
      "filters": [
        {
          "filter": "5c482c2c2abe2f07ccd5d428",
          "value": 7
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c392abe2f07ccd5d429",
          "value": 3
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c462abe2f07ccd5d42a",
          "value": 5
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c4d2abe2f07ccd5d42b",
          "value": 2
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c562abe2f07ccd5d42c",
          "value": true
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c612abe2f07ccd5d42d",
          "value": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "memberOnly": false,
    "feature": false,
    "active": true,
    "Category": "5c45af3b5ccf2c20833a547a"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5c484ec4cb1e150b1efce101",
    "details": {
      "title": "Villa 2",
      "description": "Description about Villa 2"
    },
    "options": {
      "features": [
        "5c482b1ff9f18807694040c6",
        "5c482b2ef9f18807694040c7",
        "5c482b3af9f18807694040c8",
        "5c482b49f9f18807694040c9"
      ],
      "filters": [
        {
          "filter": "5c482c2c2abe2f07ccd5d428",
          "value": 5
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c392abe2f07ccd5d429",
          "value": 7
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c462abe2f07ccd5d42a",
          "value": 2
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c4d2abe2f07ccd5d42b",
          "value": 6
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c562abe2f07ccd5d42c",
          "value": true
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c612abe2f07ccd5d42d",
          "value": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "memberOnly": false,
    "feature": false,
    "active": true,
    "Category": "5c45af3b5ccf2c20833a547a"
  }
]
```

I need a mongoose aggregation to be able to filter between objects based on the filter and its value

example:
i need to filter listings that have 
filter "5c482c2c2abe2f07ccd5d428" with a value $gte:4
filter "5c482c4d2abe2f07ccd5d42b" with a value $gte:3
filter "5c482c612abe2f07ccd5d42d" with a true value

When I filter the expected result should be

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5c484ec4cb1e150b1efce101",
    "details": {
      "title": "Villa 1",
      "description": "Description about Villa 1"
    },
    "options": {
      "features": [
        "5c482b1ff9f18807694040c6",
        "5c482b2ef9f18807694040c7",
        "5c482b3af9f18807694040c8",
        "5c482b49f9f18807694040c9"
      ],
      "filters": [
        {
          "filter": "5c482c2c2abe2f07ccd5d428",
          "value": 7
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c392abe2f07ccd5d429",
          "value": 3
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c462abe2f07ccd5d42a",
          "value": 5
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c4d2abe2f07ccd5d42b",
          "value": 2
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c562abe2f07ccd5d42c",
          "value": true
        },
        {
          "filter": "5c482c612abe2f07ccd5d42d",
          "value": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "memberOnly": false,
    "feature": false,
    "active": true,
    "Category": "5c45af3b5ccf2c20833a547a"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution was

```
Listing.find({
                $and: [{
                    'options.filters': {
                        $elemMatch: {
                            filter: this.mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5c482c2c2abe2f07ccd5d428'),
                            value: {$gte: 4}
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    'options.filters': {
                        $elemMatch: {
                            filter: this.mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5c482c4d2abe2f07ccd5d42b'),
                            value: {$gte: 3}
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    'options.filters': {
                        $elemMatch: {
                            filter: this.mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5c482c612abe2f07ccd5d42d'),
                            value: true
                        }
                    }
                });
```